# Facebook Like button in phonegap app?

Tags: cordova

I would like to implement some facebook action in my app and I wonder:

What is the best way to have a Facebook Like button or a share button in my app? 
Is there any other buttons for sharing - writing to the users wall on 
facebook?

I use jqtouch and phonegap for my app, I also use the childbrowser and 
the FBConnect with the childbrowser to log in the user to facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just generate your own like button and paste the code in your index.html file?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: that won't work - IOS will pop a dialog in a new page if you are not logged in.  Pulls you out of app to open a new window in Safari - last I checked that didn't work either...